# Pauli Exclusion principle: Query

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, pauli-exclusion-principle

The definition that I have concluded is that:

**No two fermions can exist in the state, or quantum state, unless they have opposite spins.**
Am I right in saying this? They can have the same azimuthal number, the same principle quantum number, and thus the same magnetic number but if they have a different spin it's alright?

Any clarification appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/582934/can-why-electrons-exist-in-shells-be-explained-by-the-pauli-exclusion-principle/582967#582967

Comment: Ah so they can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pauli exclusion principle is -
"No two fermions can occupy same quantum state."
i.e. If two electrons have same principal, azimuthal and magnetic no. then they must have different spin quantum number.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes - if they do have the same azimuthal number, the same principle quantum number, and thus the same magnetic number but if they have a different spin it's alright.
See link below for more help:
[**LINK**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/582934/can-why-electrons-exist-in-shells-be-explained-by-the-pauli-exclusion-principle/582967#582967)